# How to bind queue-triggered Azure Function to a custom object

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

While writing a queue-triggered Azure Function I read that, by default, it expects a base-64 encoded string, but that it can also bind to a POCO.

> Access the message data by using a method parameter such as `string paramName`. The
> `paramName` is the value specified in the QueueTriggerAttribute. You can bind to any of
> the following types:
>
> - Plain-old CLR object (POCO)
> - `string byte[]`
> - `QueueMessage`
>
> When binding to an object, the Functions runtime tries to deserialize the JSON payload
> into an instance of an arbitrary class defined in your code.

[[documentation]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#usage)

When I try this, the exception is...

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

Tantalisingly, I've read that I should reference `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Queues`, but I can't find any examples or documentation on how to use this.

I referenced the NuGet package and Visual Studio now underlines the `QueueTriggerAttribute` as ambiguous due to being in two namespaces; When I try to fully-qualify it, I can't find it.

In several places I've found bloggers alluding to using `...Extensions.Storage...` to bind a custom object but I've been searching for over an hour and I can't find any example or clear documentation on how to achieve this.

Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While writing a queue-triggered Azure Function I read that, by default, it expects a base-64 encoded string, but that it can also bind to a POCO.

Correct, but in order to bind to a POCO the message still must be a base64 encoding string containing valid JSON that can be used to deserialize into an instance of the POCO class.

You can try it using for example the Storage Explorer:

[image]

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp3
{
    public class Function
    {
        [FunctionName("Function")]
        public void Run([QueueTrigger("queue", Connection = "MyConn")] MyObject myQueueItem, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem.Name}");
        }
    }

    public class MyObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @peter-bons - that works, but why is there an option to store as plain text? Does the queue allow it, but will only deserialise if the message is base-64 encoded? I've also read elsewhere (https://www.hiroakit.com/archives/2203) that with the Extensions NuGet package we may also specify `"messageEncoding": "none"` in the host.json file - again, is this simply _permitted_ but the in-built deserialising functionality won't work with it?